# HTML5 Video Change Src

Tags: video, mobile, video-streaming, html5-video

I've a React application that uses a video element to display a video.

I'm sharing a reference to the video element and I'm dynamically changing the src attribute of the video element.

The issue I'm facing is that in mobile, when I change the src of the video element the element goes blank and does not show any of the video content.

The audio plays just fine even after changing the src.

Note that the only time the blank video element issue appears is after changing the element and everything works just fine on PC.

I'm also using most of the available event listeners in order to determine if I should display loading icon or not etc...

Comment: There could be multiple reasons, such as the codec int he video not being supported on mobile - if you can share the code and any browser console messages form the mobile that would help narrow it down.

Comment: I have my own CMS where I upload videos and it generates multiple resolutions by using ffmpeg, what I tested right about now was that if I copy the non-generated video and paste it as some other version such as  cp media.mp4 media_360.mp4 when I switch to it it seems to work just fine, but I can also open the generated versions and they work pretty fine in the desktop browser.